# Replace back slashes with forward slashes in string (std::replace works on windows but not on linux)

Tags: c++

I was working on a small application in Windows, one of the steps is to send it a path through the command line (CMD.exe), something like this:

`c:\> my_environment_var catch folder/sub_folder/file.txt`

The program receives the path and executes a process. For this, I was asked to control two cases:

1. Transform the string entered by the user to lowercase.
2. Replace the back slashes (\) that the user enters in the route with forward slashes (/).

For example, if the user entesrs:

`c:\> my_environment_var catch FOLDER\sub_Folder\fiLE.txt`

My "control" function should process the string and return a result like this:

`folder/sub_folder/file.txt`

**All in lowercase and with forward slashes.**

To achieve this I use the following within my "control" function:

`std::transform(argument.begin(), argument.end(), argument.begin(), ::tolower);`

`std::replace(argument.begin(), argument.end(), '\\', '/');`

In Windows both functions work correctly. However in Linux (Ubuntu) only the lowercase transformation works correctly, **the replace function "removes" the back slash, something like this**:

**User enters:**

`c:\> my_environment_var catch FOLDER\sub_Folder\FiLe.txt`

**Application prints:**

`foldersub_folderfile.txt`

I've been googling for several hours now but based on what I read the std::replace should work fine.

I appreciate any ideas.

---

**EDIT:** ***************************************

---

Thanks for the support, I read that it would be necessary to share some more code, and, well, here it is:

**First step:** The user writes in the console the environment variable together with the command (the action to be performed) and the file to which this action should be applied. For this case I use the `catch` command which copies the file name to another file (indexing).

`c:\> my_env_var catch FOLDER\sub_Folder\FiLe.txt`

**Step two:** The application receives the parameters through the main function, creates a vector of strings, and sends the vector to a function to be processed (The Starter class is initialized with the values of argc and argv).

```
#include "Starter.h"
// more includes
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string current_path = fs::current_path().string();
    std::vector<std::string> arg_container;
    Starter starter(current_path, argc, argv);
    starter.input_formatter(arg_container);
    // more code...
}
```

**Step three:** The input_formatter () function receives this data and does the process, which is essentially simple:

- Copies the values ​​stored in the variable argv and adds them to the vector created previously.
- Go through the vector (recently filled with the data from argv) executing two actions: The first is to transform the text to lowercase and the second is to replace the back slashes with forward slashes.

`

```
//some includes
using std::string;
using std::vector;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

Starter::Starter(string current_path, int argument_count, char* argument_values[])
    : current_path{current_path},
      argument_count{argument_count},
      argument_values{argument_values} {}

void Starter::input_formatter(vector<string>& arg_container) {
    std::copy(argument_values, argument_values + argument_count, std::back_inserter(arg_container));
    for (auto& argument : arg_container) {
        std::transform(argument.begin(), argument.end(), argument.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::replace(argument.begin(), argument.end(), '\\', '/');
    }
}
```

**Step four:** Let's say that once the data is modified, the vector is traversed and printed. Actually, other actions are performed with the vector but that is not important since these actions are performed with the result.

**Problem:** When the vector is printed, The string corresponding to the path that the user entered, does not have any slash. (that is, regardless of the names of the folders and / or files.). Like this:

`foldersub_folderfile.txt`

This only happens on Linux (I have only tried Ubuntu), on Windows everything works as it should.

PD. I'm sure it's a silly mistake, but I've really searched for the solution and still can't find it. Thank you!

Comment: If you tried to test it using a string literal, the problem might be caused because `\s` in `FOLDER\sub` is considered some sort of escape character. Try using a raw string literal instead like in this example https://godbolt.org/z/W4rrzr

Comment: @PetokLorand Escape characters applies only for the compiler when reading the source code. If the string comes at runtime, from the command line in this case, nothing is escaped.

Comment: You will need to show full code, but my guess is the same as @petoklorand.

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, I know about that, but the code should behave as expected given run time string input. The problem should manifest only when using string literals. https://godbolt.org/z/6ze53c

Comment: It should work fine, and it does work fine. The problem really is in your code. But I bet the problem disappears when you reduce your code to a minimal example. You could make a 3-line `main` function which reads the input, replaces the slashes, and outputs the result.

Comment: On an unrelated note, Ubuntu will be case-sensitive, so the user **should** be able to enter `FiLe.txt`. Don't change that to `file.txt`, which is an entirely unrelated file. You might as well change it to `filenotfound.txt`, because that will be the result. The forward slashes will work. The whole requirement seems strange, though, as it mixes the the forward slashes of Linux and the case-insensitivity of Windows. I'd probably chase down the person who came up with the idea instead of implementing it.

Comment: @PetokLorand, Maybe, I'll test that as soon as I'm on my computer. ... PD. I just updated my post, I have put all the code related to the problem, hopefully you can check it. Thanks!

Comment: @Botje, I just updated my post, I have put all the code related to the problem, hopefully you can check it. Thanks!

Comment: @MSalters, I will try to reduce it to see if I find the problem, to be honest the code is already very short, so I did not try to reduce it further but maybe I can find something that I have not noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, my guess would be that the issue is not with your code: it's with the way you are providing input to your program. Unlike on Windows, Linux doesn't use `\` as a path separator, and instead it's usually given special meaning as an "escape character"—much like in C++. As such, your shell is likely parsing out the backslashes before they ever reach your program.

In particular, if you are using `bash`, then a backslash preserves the literal meaning of the following character (and the backslash is removed). If you want to preserve backslashes in your input, try escaping them:

```sh
my_environment_var catch FOLDER\\sub_Folder\\fiLE.txt
```

An alternative method is to enclose your string in single-quotes, which disables the special behaviour of all characters within them:

```sh
my_environmnent_var catch 'FOLDER\sub_Folder\fiLE.txt'
```

(See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01) for precise details on the behaviour of backslashes in POSIX shells.)